# Opscode Chef Server / Workstation force commands from server

Tags: amazon-ec2, chef-infra, chef-recipe

**Background** : Chef Server Version 12 and a Windows workstation SDK 0.10 targeting windows nodes

I've created recipes and bootstrapped local windows servers into the Chef manager and applied recipes so the very basics are all working.

**Question** : when running the bootstrap commands for a hosted server (e.g azure / aws) *I need the command to come from the Chef Server not the workstation*.

I had hoped that the knife.rb with the Chef_server_url would force all commands to come from there.

WireShark shows the WinRM connections trying to come from my workstation.

Is there any setting I can implement that forces this in the knife.rb or elsewhere?

I had tried to add the following from searches but they've not been successful :

- chef_zero.enabled                    false
- local_mode                           false

Is this resolved through Chef Provisioning rather than Chef knife commands?

many thanks in advance for any assistance you can give.

Comment: You have to launch the commands from the chef-server itself (as if it was a workstation) or to review how you do things. Chef is a pull model, bootstrap is only one way to get the client installed on a target machine, without knowledge on how you provision those machines we can't help (and there's chances this will be highly opinionated)

Comment: This is not correct, please remove this comment.

Answer (score 1):

"when running the bootstrap commands for a hosted server (e.g azure / aws) I need the command to come from the Chef Server not the workstation." is not correct. Knife commands that manipulate servers go directly from your workstation, and this is how it is supposed to work. The way the bootstrap functions is it starts the cloud machine using the relevant provider API, then connects to the new VM via SSH or WinRM and installs Chef, and then launches chef-client using a configuration file based on your knife settings (this is where `chef_server_url` comes in).